# useEffect how to compare previous and updated props

Tags: reactjs

I'm converting class-based `Heading` component to functional component but that component is using 3 lifecycle hooks `componentDidMount`, `componentWillUnmount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

I replaced `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` but how to replace `componentDidUpdate`? It is comparing updated `prop` value with old `prop` value.

[Codesandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/embed/epic-booth-94v7x)

**App Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Heading } from "./components/Heading";
import { HeadingHook } from "./components/HeadingHook";

export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    flag: false,
    mountUnmount: true
  };

  toggleChangeFlag = () => {
    if (this.state.mountUnmount) {
      this.setState({
        flag: !this.state.flag
      });
    }
  };

  toggleMountUnmount = () => {
    this.setState({
      flag: false,
      mountUnmount: !this.state.mountUnmount
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <p>Controls :</p>
          <button onClick={this.toggleChangeFlag}>Change Flag</button>
          <button onClick={this.toggleMountUnmount}>Mount & Unmount</button>
        </div>
        {this.state.mountUnmount && <Heading flag={this.state.flag} />}
        {/* Comment above line to use useEffect Heading Component */}
        {/* {this.state.mountUnmount && <HeadingHook flag={this.state.flag} />} */}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**Class-based Heading Component:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class Heading extends Component {

    handleProps() {
        if (this.props.flag) {
            alert(this.props.flag);
        } else {
             alert(this.props.flag);
        }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleProps();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.handleProps();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.flag !== prevProps.flag) {
            this.handleProps();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
    }

}
```

**useEffect Heading Component:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export const HeadingHook = (props) => {
  const handleProps = () => {
    if (props.flag) {
      alert(props.flag);
    } else {
      alert(props.flag);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleProps();
    return () => {
      handleProps();
    };
  });

  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to pass a dependency array to useEffect to make sure when the effect runs. In the current implementation of yours, useEffect is not only called on initial render but on each render. To call it on an initial render only, you need to pass an empty array as the second argument. However if you also want the effect to run on a param change, you pass in that param in the dependency array.

Secondly, Functional components don't have `this` keyword and the props received by them are through the argument of the function.

```
const Heading = ({flag}) => {


    useEffect(() => {
        const handleProps = () => {
          if (flag) {
            alert(flag);
          } else {
            alert(flag);
          }
         };
        handleProps();
        return () => {
            handleProps();
        }

    }, [flag]);
    return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
};
```

Comment: That causes a linter warning on handleProps dependency, the solution would be `Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'handleProps' definition into its own useCallback() Hook.` (from the linter)

Comment: Since handleprops is only used inside useeffect, you can move that into th useeffect function callback itself and the. You won't need to pass it as a dependency

Comment: The reason the linter complains is because it doesn't know if handleProps has some value available in closure that may change between renders. I agree this warning is not needed in this case but since handleProps is only used in the effect you may as well create it there too.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Why `handleProps` function is written inside `useEffect` hook?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri In codesandbox link I modified `useEffect` with your code but whenever I click on `Change Flag` button `handleProps` function is executing 2 times not 1 time like class-based Heading component. Why its happening?

Answer (score 2):

New hook to use instead of `useEffect`:

```js
function useComponentDidMountOrUpdate(effect, deps) {
  const prev = React.useRef(deps)

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      const unmountHandler = effect(prev.current)
      prev.current = deps
      return unmountHandler
    },
    deps
  )
}
```

Using the hook:

```js
useComponentDidMountOrUpdate(
  (prevDeps) => {
    const prevDep1 = prevDeps[1]

    if (dep1 !== prevDep1) {
      // dep1 changed
    }

    return () => { /* unmount handler */ }
  },
  [dep0, dep1, dep2]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for prop updates by using `useEffect` this way

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const Heading = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleProps = () => {
      if (props.flag) {
        alert(props.flag);
      } else {
        alert(props.flag);
      }
    };

    handleProps();
    return () => {
        handleProps();
    }
  }, [props.flag]);
  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
};
```

Adding the `[props.flag]` at the end of the `useEffect` allows for it to act as a dependency array where the useEffect hook will only fire when the `prop.flag` value in the component changes. Thus when you update or change this value from your parent component, the effect will be triggered much like the way `componentDidUpdate` does.

Answer (score 1):

when new props being passed in , the cleanup will run before the effect being applied, the cleanup function will not depend on Flag so we can simply have two useEffect.

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react";

const handleProps = (props) => {
  if (props) {
    console.log(props);
  } else {
    console.log(props);
  }
}

export const Heading = ({ flag }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("mount")
      handleProps(flag);
    }, [flag]);

    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        console.log("unmount")
        handleProps(flag)
      };
    }, []);

  return <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const prevSearchText = useRef();

useEffect(() => {

        return (function(searchText) {

            return function() {
                prevSearchText.current = searchText;
            }
        })(props.searchText)

    }, [props.searchText])
```

Using a closure in useEffect cleanup, and providing right dependencies to useEffect, should help

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a second argument to useEffect(). The second argument will be an array with the flag prop. Every time the flag prop changes the useEffect method will be triggered.

```
useEffect(() => {
  handleProps();
  
  return () => {
    handleProps();
  }
}, [props.flag]);
```

Comment: There is no `this` in a function component. and you cant `useEffect()` in a class component

Comment: Thank you @Jim I have made the correction.